# Add characters to the end of a string using regex notepad2

Tags: regex, notepad2

I have a massive string (a SQL query..) that I have written out in notepad2.  I'm using Java, and I was just wondering if there was a fast and easy way to add something to the end of each line? For example:

```
String query = "" 
+ " select column1
+ " , column2
+ " , column3
+ " from table
);
//want to add \n" at the end of each line
```

Comment: notepad++ has a macro record and playback.. not sure if yours does.

Comment: Is this related to Java or to notepad?

Comment: Notepad, apologies. I guess I sort of did imply a java element to this, huh?

Comment: @RyanDenny Are you using that in *Notepad++* or *Notepad2*? I think you are using Notepad++, the accepted answer works in Notepad++.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Find: `(.)$` 
Replace: `\1\\n"`

[Here's](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) a good regex tutorial.

Comment: This is the bom. Been looking for this for donno how long. +100

Comment: This `(.)$` does not do what you may think it does in **Notepad2**. It will match `(%)` at the end of the line,  and contains no capturing group. The `(` and `)` must be escaped to form a capturing group in Notepad2 POSIX regex. It seems most people think the question is related to Notepad++.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
2. mark regular expressions option
3. search for `$` - this means "end of line"
4. replace with `\\n"`

OR simpler

1. select lines that you want to edit
2. <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> / same as `edit`->`block`->`modify lines`
3. in `append text to lines` place `\n"`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still here 5 years later, and you are attempting to add something onto the end a line for a large non-code file (and don't want to use REGEX), there are helpful online converter tools like https://pinetools.com/add-text-each-line.

Helped me out a bunch for creating CSV files for a neural network I was making

Answer (score 0):

```
ctrl+h
```

make sure regex is on.

```
find: (.)\r\n

replace: \1 + "\\\n"\r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

In Regex you can group expressions using () - Parenthesis, and represent them as \1, \2, etc.
So, anything like this can be appended as follows:

Find: (.*);
Replace: \1 *your_new_text* ;

Comment: @Confiqure This answer does provide an answer to the question OP asked.  In fact, this answer is extremely similar to the accepted answer.  I think you need to pay closer attention when reviewing.